# Sergen : syntax erros despite rebuilt

Tags: c#

For one of my internship mission, I need to use a C# app-builder, [serenity.is](https://serenity.is) with Visual Studio 2015. I'm following [this official tutorial](https://www.gitbook.com/book/volkanceylan/serenity-guide/details).
More precisely, I followed the begin of the tutorial p 43. (I'm just adapting it to what I do, I join the code at the end of the post). 
Nothing is going wrong till p 49. The code generator of the app-builder, sergen.exe, is creating some code (I don't have the detail of what he creates but it doesn't seem to be important).

They ask me to "rebuild all", what I did, and everything should work smoothly.

> As project is  modified,   Visual  Studio  will    ask if  you want    to  reload  changes,    click   Reload  All.
>
> REBUILD    the Solution    and then    press   F5  to  launch  application.(tutoriel)
>   [image: This Rebuild thing]

Nevertheless, when i compile and execute my code, I've got a bunch of syntax error which shouldn't happen.

[image: some syntax errors]

You can find the code of my migration file below, but I don't think it is the problem.

```
using FluentMigrator;
using System;
using FluentMigrator.Infrastructure;

namespace Serene3.Migrations.DefaultDB
{

    [Migration(20170802070000)]
    public class DefaultDB_20170802_070000_TcpDump : Migration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Create.Schema("tcpdump");

            Create.Table("TCPDump").InSchema("tcpdump")
                .WithColumn("TimeStp").AsString(16).Nullable()
                .WithColumn("IdTransmission").AsInt32().Identity().PrimaryKey().NotNullable()
                .WithColumn("IdSource").AsString(32).Nullable()
                .WithColumn("IdDestination").AsString(32).Nullable()
                .WithColumn("PortSource").AsString(16).Nullable()
                .WithColumn("PortDestination").AsString(16).Nullable()
                .WithColumn("-->").AsInt32().NotNullable()
                .WithColumn("<--").AsInt32().NotNullable();


        }
        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to stay as close as the tutorial as possible. I probably forgot to do something, but I can't find what.

Is there any Serenity user which could help?

Feel free to ask any other details

Comment: To be honest, column names like `"<--"` don't really look *"as close as the tutorial as possible"* to me. Check the generated files, whether the strange column names are at fault... the "Syntaxfehler > erwartet" could originate from it

Comment: That was the error ! I though the origin was in a false manipulation of the serenity software, in which case I actually stayed as close to the tutorial as possible ^^. If you want to publish an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that all column names are supported by the tool. Column names like `"-->"` and `"<--"` would need special syntax in SQL and can't be used as property names in generated code files.

Use property-ready names without special characters or spaces. If you need special names, consult the tools documentation and make sure to use supported techniques.